# Multiple RSS in one UITableView With Different XML Tags

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uitableview, rss

I am trying to set up a `UITableView` in my application that will display several different RSS feeds.  Basically, one table for a News, Calendar, and Audio podcast.  The issue is that not all of the feeds have the same tags.  Some use `<link>` while others use `<guid>`.  How can I go about setting up the code to handle different kinds of RSS?  I have an `NSObject` called `RSSEntry` that takes strings from each of the tags to reuse later in setting up the table, but I get a nil argument if I try to get a `<link>` tag from one of the ones that uses `<guid>`.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self refresh];
}
- (void)refresh {
    self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.feeds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://ipreacher.wordpress.com/feed",@"http://www.316apps.com/Fritch/Sermons.xml",
                  nil];
    for (NSString *feed in _feeds) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feed];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [_queue addOperation:request];
    }

}
- (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

    NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {            

        NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];                    

        NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

            NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
            NSString *articleUrl = [item valueForChild:@"link"];            
            NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];        
            NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
            NSString *articleContent = [item valueForChild:@"content:encoded"];


            RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle
                                                      articleTitle:articleTitle
                                                        articleUrl:articleUrl
                                                       articleDate:articleDate
                                                      articleContent:articleContent] autorelease];
            [entries addObject:entry];

        }      
    }

}
```

Comment: You need code that knows how to parse each type of RSS feed and understands what tags it uses.

Comment: @rmaddy but how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Write a class for each feed. Each class knows how to parse a specific feed. Each should return the data formatted into a common data set that can be used by your table view's data source.

Comment: @rmaddy The issue is that they are all RSS feeds, not one RSS and one ATOM, so there's no difference except some have more tags or things like difference from link or guid.

Comment: I understand that. But you need different code that knows how to parse each feed since each feed returns different XML.

Comment: @rmaddy Obviously I need different code, which is why I came to SO, not to be told I need different code.

Comment: Which was the point of my 2nd comment. Write a different class to handle each different feed.

Comment: rmaddy's point is that you have to customize the code based upon the characteristics of each feed. I have the same problem with JSON from the same API. The parsing has to be customized with if/then's depending upon the peculiarities of each record.

Comment: you should go ahead and look at [this library](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) or if you don't find it relevant, search for "rss" and select objective-c filter on github.